# Traducir este código a vb.net

Tags: vb.net

Hola quiero traducir este pequeño visual basic para .net la cuestión es que no tengo mucha experiencia con este lenguaje de programación. Y el problema se me presenta sobre todo en el for el código en c# es:

```
//var stream
Stream stream = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("Manifest");
//Console.WriteLine(stream);
FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(appDataPath+ @"\tola.exe", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
for (int i = 0; i < stream.Length; i++)
    fileStream.WriteByte((byte)stream.ReadByte());
fileStream.Close();
RunInternal(appDataPath + @"\tola.exe", "1234");
```

Intente algo parecido en vb.net:

```vb
Dim stream As Stream = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("skip.skip.exe")
'Console.WriteLine(stream);
Using outFile As New System.IO.FileStream(appDataPath+"\tola.exe", IO.FileMode.Create, IO.FileAccess.Write)
    For i = 0  To stream.length Step 1
        outFile.Read((byte)stream.ReadByte())
    Next
    outFile.Close()
End Using
```

Pero me devuelve errores en `readbyte()`, los errores son:

> '.' expected. (BC30287) - 
>       'Byte' is a type and cannot be used as an expression. (BC30108) - 
>       'inFile' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level. (BC30451) -

Comment: si deceas convertir tu codigo de Vb.net a c# hay una web que lo realiza esta es la pagina :

http://converter.telerik.com/

Comment: si pero el código lo destroza o esta muy mal los for etc..

Comment: podrias poner la imagen del error que te sale por favor.

Answer (score 0):

Veo dos errores en esa instrucción:

En el código original es una operación de escritura (WriteByte) mientras que en el traducido estás utilizando una instrucción de lectura (Read)

Por otro lado el anteponer el tipo entre paréntesis ((byte)stream.ReadByte()) se utiliza para realizar una conversión de tipos pero es una sintaxis propia de C#. No te va a funcionar en VB.Net. Deberías utilizar el método CType o simplemente no realizar la conversión ya que ésta la realizará de forma automática .NET entre los tipos Integer (tipo devuelto por ReadByte) y Byte (tipo resperado por WriteByte):

```
outFile.WriteByte(stream.ReadByte())
```